# Register value debugging

Tags: linux, kernel, paging, mips, objdump

I have an objdump of the crashing method. I found that the crash is due to a bad memory access. The memory address is present in the MIPS register a0. Is there a way to track on how the register got this address other than backtracking (walkthrough) the objdump step by step(a0 got it from s3 and so on).

And I have one more question.

How is paging done in kernel. There must be no concept of Virtual Address in Kernel since all of them are already in memory. This question I got since in my crash there is something called BADVA(is it BAD Virtual Address) holding a bad address.

Here is the crash report

```
Cpu 0
Registries dump
Status: 10000302    KERNEL EXL 
**Cause : 00803c08    TLBL**
**BadVA : fdca9b68**
PrId  : 01019378
```

Comment: You mean an "objdump" in the sense of a disassembly?  Generally the proper tool for this is a debugger like gdb.  And unless the crashing code was written in assembly, you should be looking at the C source level and not raw registers.  That's what the debugger is for.

Comment: Yes . Its a disassembly. And it was a one time crash and never happened again. 

I need to check if the address is passed from the user space.

Comment: OK, I missed that this was in the kernel.  That makes using a debugger significantly harder, but still not impossible (google `kgdb`).  But you should have an OOPS report in your kernel logs that should help you with analysis -- generally it's much easier to look at a stack trace and reason about how the crash happened than it is to start at a bad address in isolation and work through a disassembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proximate cause of the crash is that no TLB entry matches the virtual address in BadVA, and that this happened while the CPU is in exception mode.

The BadVA address (fdca9b68) is in the KSEG2 region of the virtual address space. This region is used for mapped addresses in the MIPS Linux Kernel (typically used for Kernel Modules). I would suspect a bug in a kernel module.

If you want to understand what is going on in a MIPS CPU you should buy and study [See MIPS Run](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120884216).

Comment: Thank you. Just confused on what to do further with this bad address. The above thing i pasted is a kernel panic with kernel log buffer containing 
    Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address

And this never happened again. What are the chances that made this as such a rare occurance?